# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms to mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi using Java

Tags: java

I have a SQL query which returns one column value-2020-07-01 03:43:30.0(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms).I want to convert this into 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi' format using Java code.How to do this with Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two different `DateTimeFormatter`s:

```
DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
DateTimeFormatter resultFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Where `parseFormat` is used for parsing and `resultFormat` is used to produce the `String` from the parsed date:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-07-01 03:43:30.0", parseFormat);
String result = ldt.format(resultFormat);
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints:

```
07/01/2020 03:43
```